# How to remove search icon in SearchBar for android and ios in nativescript angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing android and ios application using nativescript angular. I want to remove the search icon inside SearchBar for both android and ios platform.In android I have done something like this:

```
 searchBarLoaded(event)
 {
     let searchbar=<SearchBar>event.object;
     var androidSearchBar=searchbar.nativeView;
    let searchIcon androidSearchBar.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchIcon.android.setVisibility(android.View.GONE);

 }
```

But it was not worked.Can you help me how to remove the search icon inside searchbar?

Comment: I was in the same situation & I ended up writing myself a component Searchbar.

Comment: Component searchbar means with textfield?

Comment: Yes. I use autocomplete textfield with image button

Comment: Ok thankyout.i will try.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Even in Android there are similar solutions given like one you are using in many SO threads but it doesn't seem to actually work neither marked as accepted.

Comment: any possibility to overcome this.because i want the searchbar like whatsapp search bar